# Como eu retiro algum dado de uma lista

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que eu preciso retirar os dados de uma lista em Python, mas quando coloco o índice que desejo, ele sai somente a primeira letra, ou o primeiro caractere.

```
{"date":"2020-12-02","opening":99131.18,"closing":100614.99,"lowest":97500,"highest":101999.99,"volume":11373667.10536848,"quantity":113.46703469,"amount":5471,"avg_price":100237.63409735}
```

Esse é o output, gostaria de retirar os dados, por exemplo, pegar os dados do date e colocar em uma variável.

```
response = requests.get(f'https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/day-summary/{year}/{month}/{day}/')

print(response.text[2]) #aqui sai somente a letra "d"
```

Comment: Creio que as duas perguntas sugeridas acima no box azul resolvem o seu problema: a primeira diz como obter os dados (usando `json()` em vez de `text`), e a segunda tem uma boa explicação sobre como obter os dados do JSON

Comment: Esse é um formato de dicionário { },  poderá acessa pela chave e acessa o valor que deseja l.